# How to add a public key in the android project

Tags: android

I got a public key from the android market, i want to know how to add that public key in my android project, can anyone tell me how to add the public key in my android project,

Answer (score 0):

The only reason you would need to use that key is if you were implementing a service like, but not limited to, [in app billing](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/billing/index.html). In such a case, you'll need to consult the documentation for that service as to where you are supposed to put the key, as it varies.

Answer (score 0):

On your eclipse android project, right click and select Android Tools -> select "Export Signed Application Package. Follow that,use your keys.

Comment: If he has received the key from the Play Store, then it is not the signing certificate. It is the PGP key used for In App billing etc.